# How to pass selected drop down menu value to JSON function via JQuery/Javascript properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile, Javascript, HTML, JSON, AJAX, PHP and MySQL to dynamically display values from the database onto a webpage.

I have a few elements working together. First a drop down menu that populates a list view. The drop down menu elements are obtained from the database. This is done via the "on change" method, when activated it passes the selected option and the ID of the drop down menu to a JSON function, which takes care of retrieving the data from the database with the help of PHP and functions. I also have a radio button that works as a filter to the type of results that are to be retrieved from the database and displayed on the list view.

My problem is hopefully simpler than it looks. I am trying to pass my JSON function the value of the selected option from the drop down menu. I know that the JSON wants an object, but I am having problems doing this.

To illustrate how I try to do this, let's say I have a drop down list with fruits, I have a radio button that allows you to choose from Red fruits or Green fruits, and a list view to display my results:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">

        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="red" value="1" checked="checked" onchange="change_fruit_color('red');"/>
        <label for="red">Red Fruits</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="green" value="2" onchange="change_fruit_color('green');"/>
        <label for="green">Green Fruits</label>

    </fieldset>
</div>

<li>
    <label for="fruit" class="select">Fruits</label>
    <select name="fruit" id="fruit" data-mini="true" onclick="populate_list('fruit', this);" onchange="clear_dropdown('fruit'); refresh_dropdown('fruit');">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Note that I have a few extra functions, refresh_dropdown() and clear_dropdown() handle refreshing my drop down list items, nothing to worry about there. The populate_list function works good too. The issue is regarding the logic of the change_fruit_color() function:

```
function change_fruit_color(fruit_color)
{
    var selected_value = $("#fruits option:selected").text();

    if(selected_value)
    {
        switch(fruit_color)
        {
            case "red":
            populate_list('red', selected_value);
            break;

            case "practice":
            populate_list('green', selected_value);
            break;
        }
        clear_dropdown("fruit");
        refresh_dropdown("fruit");
    }
}

function populate_list(selected_fruit, this_menu)
{
    var find_fruit_url = server_root_url + 'fruit/find_fruit.php';
    var value = this_menu.options[this_menu.selectedIndex].value;

    var params = {
        control: selected_fruit,
        value: value
    };

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: find_fruit_url,
    async:false,
    data: params,
        success: function(json){
            json_populate(json, selected_fruit, value);
        }
    });            
}
```

As you can see, I can call the populate_list three times; once within the "onclick" function of the drop down list, the other within the change_fruit_color that's called via the "onchange" event in the radio button box. In here is where the issue lies.

I tried to make a sample of my general issue so that I write way less code for all of you to read through. Any help on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `selected_value` as the second argument to `populate_list`, but your second argument (`this_menu`) is supposed to be the `select` if you want to get the `options` property on it. I would rename the `this_menu` argument to `selected_value` and use that instead of fetching the value from the `select` again.

Comment: You have the right idea, but renaming this_menu to selected_value cannot change the outcome (just tested it). What you suggested was to  rename the variables, but I think that what must be done is changing what value they hold into whatever JSON needs. I think JSON wants an "object" to be passed and I must be passing something else onto it, perhaps a string or something it doesn't like, because I still get that error after renaming this_menu into selected_value. Any thoughts?

Comment: I was hoping that you would see that the problem is you are passing the `select_value` as a string, then using it like a `select` object. I did say "use that instead of fetching the value from the select again"; not just a simple rename. Remove the line `var value = this_menu.options[this_menu.selectedIndex].value;` and change any references to `value` to `selected_value` in `populate_list`. That will remove that source of error. Whether there are further sources of error remains to be seen ;)

Comment: You are absolutely right Mike, I tested your solution and it would work, but I realized that I have no choice but to get a String from HTML and pass it as an object for my JSON function, instead of the other way around. Do you think this is possible? To obtain a String from HTML and convert it into an object that will be passed to a JSON function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "get a String from HTML ans pass it as an object for my JSON function". What "JSON function" do you mean? You're already getting a string from the selected option and putting it in your `params` object, which is passed to `$.ajax()`...

Comment: Sorry for the delay been busy with work. What I am trying to say is that I get an error because I am passing a String to something that is asking for an Object. I wonder if the solution would be to get the String value, convert it into an Object and give it to the function so that it does not complain. If that's not possible or even practical then what other solution do you see?

Comment: Strings are Objects, so that's not going to help. The problem is most likely that the function to which you are passing the String expects there to be a particular property or method on the object, which String does not have. You need to pass the correct type of Object, not just any Object. I'll ask again, what is the function which is expecting the object, and what is the code which calls that function? With those two pieces of information, I'm sure we could figure out the solution.

Comment: The exact issue occurs in the function `populate_list(selected_fruit, this_menu)` specifically `var value = this_menu.options[this_menu.selectedIndex].value;` I did more testing where I output `alert(this_menu);` prior to doing `var value = this_menu.options[this_menu.selectedIndex].value;`. The output is [object Object] but I determined that it's looking for is actually [object HTMLSelectElement]. You are right, it's not that they're not objects but something about [object Object] is making `var value = anything in the shape of [object Object]` very upset. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have to pass the `select` object around rather than changing `populate_list` to take a string, but if you must, change your `change_fruit_color` function to pass it. IOW, change `populate_list('green', selected_value);` to `populate_list('green', document.getElementById('fruit'))`, and likewise wherever `populate_list` is called.

Comment: That is actually not causing an error and it's going through! I just don't get any search results but then that's another issue. Thanks for all your help! I hope it's ok if I comment again regarding any immediate issues

Comment: To anyone who reads these comments, the solution was to use `document.getElementByID('fruit')` to get the much needed `[object HTMLSelectElement]` object and pass it to the `populate_list` function as example `populate_list('green', document.getElementById('fruit'));` kudos to Mike McCaughan for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Please post your json_populate function to be check what's going on there.
Maybe a time saver would be how you properly format a JSON array. Remember that you've have to use the following notation when dealind with JSON arrays...

```
var myJsonArray = {
                    "name_1": value1,
                    "name_2": value2
                  };
```

So maybe your param's var should go as this:

```
var params = {
    "control": selected_fruit,
    "value": value
};
```

Hope this helps.
Luis M.

Comment: I have tested my json_populate and I can assure you that it is working well. The error that occurs pertains to the populate_list function, web inspector says this:

type error: "undefined" is not an object (evaluating 'this_fruit.options[this_fruit.selectedIndex]')

That's why I think that the issue is that I am passing something to JSON that it doesn't like, but I don't know how to fix it. How can I pass the current selected value to JSON so that it does not complain?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by using this code:

```
$.post(urlpath,formData,'json')

    .done(function(data) {

    $.each(data.collection, function (key, value) {
    $("#priorityid").append("<option value='"+value.codemaster_detls_name+"'>" + value.codemaster_detls_name + "</option>");

})
```

Priorityid is the id of the particular list, codemaster_detls_name is my mysql table name from which I am retrieving data.